# how to select all configuration files (files that ends with rc) in the .editorconfig file?

Tags: configuration-files, atom-editor, editorconfig

In my `.editoconfig` file I want to select all **configuration files** like `.bowerrc`, `.jscsrc`, `.jshintrc` and so on. The file must begin with a dot and end with `rc`.

I tried with `[.*rc]` but it does not work!

How can I select all those files in the `.editorconfig` file?

Comment: That should work. Have you tried testing that without a `.` to see if EditorConfig is working at all? What editor are you using? Do you have the plugin installed (if needed)?

Comment: @TreyHunner I am using atom and the plugin is installed and works for other files. I tried to just write `*rc` but still doesn't work

Comment: The core EditorConfig library should find rules applying to hidden files. I'd guess this might be a bug in the Atom plugin. If you can reproduce it on a particular repository or set of files, you might want to try filing a bug report: https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-editorconfig/issues
Good luck!